# InfluxDB Grafana one graph with different CQs and RPs

Tags: grafana, influxdb, policies, retention

We try to create retention policies on our data so we can reduce amount of data we store. The point is to have a graph divided into tree parts where every part would have different CQ and RP as well I think.

So graph in Grafana would show 3rd part where is older data in 5mins intervals, 2nd part in 3mins intervals and last 1st part would be shown in real time.

I have three retention policies for each part one and three CQs for each of them, however, it doesn’t do the job :frowning:

```
autogen  168h0m0s 168h0m0s           1        true
rp.1part 1h0m0s   1h0m0s             1        false
rp.2part 2h0m0s   1h0m0s             1        false
rp.3part 3h0m0s   1h0m0s             1        false


> create continuous query "cq_part1" ON grafanatest1 BEGIN SELECT mean(*) INTO "rp.1part"."downsampled_1part" FROM "cpu_load_short" GROUP BY time(2m) END
> create continuous query "cq_part2" ON grafanatest1 BEGIN SELECT mean(*) INTO "rp.2part"."downsampled_2part" FROM "cpu_load_short" GROUP BY time(4m) END
> create continuous query "cq_part3" ON grafanatest1 BEGIN SELECT mean(*) INTO "rp.3part"."downsampled_3part" FROM "cpu_load_short" GROUP BY time(6m) END
```

Any advise would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance for any help!